# Python, мутация, неверный результат

Tags: python, list, список

Функция modify_list(l), которая должна принимать на вход список целых чисел, удалять из него все нечётные значения, а чётные нацело делить на два. Где ошибка?

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 20]
def modify_list(l):
    count = 0
    for i in l:
        if i%2 == 0:
            x = i//2
            l.pop(count)
            l.insert(count,x)
            count+=1
        else:
            l.pop(count)

modify_list(l)
print(l)
```

Мой неверный результат работы программы:

```
[4, 10, 6, 8, 20]
```

Comment: Вопрос: "Где ошибка?". Принят ответ, в котором вообще нет никаких объяснений. Вам не интересно, где ошибка? Зачем тогда спрашивать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы, изменяя длину списка, пытаетесь "на лету" вставлять элементы по старым (до удаления) индексам.

Чуть более идиоматичный вариант решения:

```
l[:] = [x//2 for x in l if x % 2 == 0]
```

результат:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 20]
def modify_list(l):
    new_list = [item // 2 for item in l if item % 2 == 0]
    l.clear()
    l += new_list
modify_list(l)
print(l)
```